# Can someone explain the benefit of the SSGI addon for Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I understand that it tries to replicate GI like Cycles, but using it creates noise, which requires more samples, which increases render times, at which point you might as well just use Cycles, which can also take advantage of the pretty decent denoise compositing node. So why is everyone going crazy over this add-on? Is it just because it can create Cycles-like results in the viewport in real-time? I feel like I’m missing something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tested but there is most likely a easy way to denoise your eevee renders. I have evem denoised non renderings in blender with great succes. Though the results may not be as good because as far as im aware the Denoiser needs to be trained on the particular noise pattern. (please correct me if im wrong)

Comment: In Case this answered your question please mark it as correct so the question gets marked as answerd. If you need further deteils ask! so everyone profits :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:** nice light bounces but faster than Cycles.

As you are aware EEVEE is a much faster render engine than Cycles. It builds on the approach of [rasterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) instead of raytracing. This means that it basically tries to calculate the color value for each pixel more directly, while [raytracer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytracing) like Cycles is taking an approach of simulating the approximate movement of light through the scene.

This leads to a variety of advantages and shortcomings. One of this shortcomings is that the dogmatic rasterization approach doesn't allow for bounce light (as this falls more into the simulation realm).

This addon works around that particular shortcoming. For example if you are dependent on the speed of EEVEE, can live with most of its shortcomings, but still need light interaction between your objects and can't bake your whole light because you for example have movement in your scene, than this is a quick way to achieve this.